# Pyspark - update column on a condition with a value from it's current row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to update a column based on a condition. If the condition passes, it should update it with a string + the current row's other column.

```
updated_df = original_df
    .withColumn(
        "url", F.when(original_df.id == 13, "something/{}".format(?) -> I want the current row's 'name' column value here.
    )
    .otherwise(original_df.url)
)
```

Is this a right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `format_string` method from pyspark.sql.functions: [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.format_string)

```py
updated_df = original_df
    .withColumn(
        "url", F.when(original_df.id == 13, F.format_string("something/%s", original_df.col_name)
    )
    .otherwise(original_df.url)
)
```